# Negating fill:currentColor

Tags: css, svg

Is there a way to negate or remove `fill: currentColor`?

```css
.svg-icon * {
  /* Targets all sub-elements so we can deliver icons with a color override of our choice */
  fill: currentColor;
}

.svg-icon.iconLogoGlyph * {
  /* How do I  negate fill: currentColor further down the cascade? */
  fill: inherit;
  /* I want the natural colors from the SVG */
}
```

```html
<svg role="icon" class="svg-icon iconLogoGlyph" width="25" height="30" viewBox="0 0 25 30"><g fill="none"><path fill="#BCBBBB" d="M21 27v-8h3v11H0V19h3v8z"></path><path fill="#F48024" d="M5.402 19.101l13.561 1.96.164-2.38-13.256-2.547-.469 2.967zM7.2 12.3l12 5.6 1.1-2.4-12-5.6-1.1 2.4zm3.4-5.9l10.2 8.5 1.7-2-10.2-8.5-1.7 2zM17.1.2L15 1.8l7.9 10.6 2.1-1.6L17.1.2zM5 25h14v-3H5v3z"></path></g></svg>
```

I have a set of icons that are authored with SVG. Some of these icons contain inline styling with color information. The most common use case is to ignore these inline fills and for them to inherit their parent's `color` by declaring `fill: currentColor` in CSS. But, in some cases, like our logo, we'd like for these embedded colors to be shown. Elsewhere, say, a footer, we'd like to override the colors with a single color of our choice.

For reasons™, I'm stuck with these classes that are in the library. Each icon has the class `svg-icon` and a more specific class, in this case `iconLogoGlyph`.

How can I negate `fill: currentColor` using only CSS if I can't touch the classes? I've experimented with `:not` to select all but `.iconLogoGlyph`, but this wouldn't let me use `fill: currentColor` when I actually need it.

What is the opposite of `fill: currentColor`? It's not `fill: inherit` or `fill: none`. I need something like `fill: just grab what's in the SVG, yo`

Comment: Are you sure that `.svg-icon:not(.iconLogoGlyph) *` does not work?

Comment: I'm definitely able to get `.svg-icon:not(.iconLogoGlyph) *` to ignore the `currentColor`, but I'd like the default state to be `currentColor` and the override to be `use natural colors`. Hmm.

Comment: That's what I meant: `.svg-icon:not(.iconLogoGlyph) * { fill: currentColor; }`, end of story.

Comment: Unfortunately, that CSS assumes "Every icon except for this one should inherit colors from its parent" when I'd like "Every icon should inherit colors from its parent unless I explicitly tell it to." It's a subtle thing, but I'd like removing the inheritance to be the override, not the inheritance to be. Hmm.

Comment: So the discerning factor is not the classes on the svg element, but something elsewhere in the tree? Then your example is misleading. Whatever the case, the solution lies with tayloring the selector, not the attribute.

Comment: I've asked if there's a way to negate fill: currentColor and you've offered a way to ignore that particular icon.

Answer (score 4):

There's a way to make this work if you modify the SVG a bit. If you, instead of this:

```xml
<path fill="#BCBBBB" d="..."></path>
```

do this:

```xml
<g fill="#BCBBBB"><path d="..."></path></g>
```

i.e. wrap all the filled shapes in groups and specify the fill on the group instead of on the path itself, then the following happens:

According to [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#FillProperty),

1. `fill` doesn't apply to `<g>` elements, so setting this property on the group doesn't hurt (as in, you don't suddenly get a filled rectangle), and
2. `fill` is inherited, and thus the `<g>`'s `fill` will apply to the `<path>`.

Next, if instead of `*` you use `*:not(g)` in your CSS (in your particular example, just using `path` would also work), then in the default case, `fill: currentColor` will tell the path to use the current color (and ignore the parent group's fill value). In the override case, where you set `fill: inherit`, you tell the path to go back to inheriting the parent's fill value.

```css
.svg-icon *:not(g) {
  fill: currentColor;
}

.svg-icon.iconLogoGlyph *:not(g) {
  fill: inherit;
}
```

```html
<!-- these two SVGs are identical except that the
     first one doesn't have the `iconLogoGlyph` class -->

<div style="color: green">

  <svg role="icon" class="svg-icon" width="25" height="30" viewBox="0 0 25 30"><g fill="none"><g fill="#BCBBBB"><path d="M21 27v-8h3v11H0V19h3v8z"></path></g><g fill="#F48024"><path fill="#F48024" d="M5.402 19.101l13.561 1.96.164-2.38-13.256-2.547-.469 2.967zM7.2 12.3l12 5.6 1.1-2.4-12-5.6-1.1 2.4zm3.4-5.9l10.2 8.5 1.7-2-10.2-8.5-1.7 2zM17.1.2L15 1.8l7.9 10.6 2.1-1.6L17.1.2zM5 25h14v-3H5v3z"></path></g></g></svg>
  
  <svg role="icon" class="svg-icon iconLogoGlyph" width="25" height="30" viewBox="0 0 25 30"><g fill="none"><g fill="#BCBBBB"><path d="M21 27v-8h3v11H0V19h3v8z"></path></g><g fill="#F48024"><path fill="#F48024" d="M5.402 19.101l13.561 1.96.164-2.38-13.256-2.547-.469 2.967zM7.2 12.3l12 5.6 1.1-2.4-12-5.6-1.1 2.4zm3.4-5.9l10.2 8.5 1.7-2-10.2-8.5-1.7 2zM17.1.2L15 1.8l7.9 10.6 2.1-1.6L17.1.2zM5 25h14v-3H5v3z"></path></g></g></svg>

</div>
```

You only have to make this SVG change to icons where you expect you might want to use the native colors. Icons that are always supposed to be filled with the current color don't need to be changed.

Comment: neat idea, although I thought the icons library was unchangeable?

Comment: The CSS classes are, but the OP didn't say the SVGs are. And since he's my coworker, I know they aren't ;)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no property value to `fill` that fulfills your requirements. The only sensible way to achieve the effect you are looking for is to use CSS selectors that match those icons you want to recolor.

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution, if you can slightly change your global `fill: currentColor` rule and SVGs which need to preserve their colors.

Change your global rule to something like this:

```
path:not(.important), circle:not(.important) {
    fill: currentColor;
}
```

And in your SVGs add `important` class to all filled parts, like:

```
<path class="important" fill="#FFF" ...
```

Unlike the `<g>` tag solution this method allows you easily replace all the needed parts automatically, using editor tools.